# SSRS. Customizing tablix. Different number of columns on each row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I need to customize my table (I don't know why It's called Tablix). On each row I need to make different number of columns.

What I mean. Here is how my table(tablix) looks like now:

[image: current tablix]

Here how It should be:

[image: tablix should be]

On first 2 rows here should be 4 columns, in 3-4th rows should be 3 columns. I've tried to merge cells in 3, 4 rows, but in this case I can't change their width irrespective of 1, 2 rows.

How It looks like after merge:

[image: after merge]

Can't change rows width of columns in 3, 4 rows without changing width of columns 1, 2 rows

Comment: If you select two cells and right click there is option for merge the cell. But I   am not sure if this is possible in `Grouping`. But check it out if that helps.

Comment: As I mentioned I tried to merge cells, It working, but I can't change columns width in 3,4 rows. Uploaded picture how It looks like after merge.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean.

Comment: So don't have ideas how to do that?

Comment: Sorry not a clue but I will look for it if found post it here

Comment: Ok, thank you for efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're simplifying the example you've given above to ask a more general question, but in the specific case you described, why not create 6 columns?

Then, on rows 1 and 2, you could merge columns 2 and 3 as well as columns 4 and 5.  And on rows 3 and 4, merge column 1 with 2, 3 with 4, and 5 with 6.

In theory, you can achieve this with any combination of rows and columns, but it can quickly get very tedious as the combinations add up.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Strange solution, but It worked for me! Thank you again!